Dynamic Any() Expression returns no results
I'm having some issues with building a dynamic expression tree. I have the basic functionality working where I can specify a property, operator and value for the expression. But I'm running into issues when trying to make an expression for a list in an object.
The object I'm trying to make the expression for looks like this (simplified)
public class Component
{
    string partNumber;
    string description;
    List<SupplierRecord> supplierRecords;
}

public class SupplierRecord
{
    string supplierName;
    string supplierPartNumber;
}

My expression builder looks like this
internal class ExpressionBuilder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a expression for a Type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type the expression applies to</typeparam>
    /// <param name="filters">List of filter parameters</param>
    /// <returns>An expression for the Type</returns>
    public static Func<T, bool>? GetExpression<T>(IList<Filter> filters)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        Expression? expression = null;

        if (filters == null || !filters.Any())
        {
            expression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Default(typeof(T)), Expression.Default(typeof(T)));
        }
        else
        {
            // Add upp all expressions
            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
                if (filter.Property == "SupplierRecords")
                {
                    MemberExpression records = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "SupplierRecords");
                    
                    ParameterExpression suppParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SupplierRecord), "s");
                    Filter newFilter = new() { Property = "SupplierPartNumber", Value = filter.Value, Operator = filter.Operator };

                    Expression ex1 = GetExpression<SupplierRecord>(suppParameter, newFilter);
                    Expression ex2 = Expression.Lambda(ex1, suppParameter);
                    MethodCallExpression anyCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", [typeof(SupplierRecord)], records, ex2);

                    if (expression == null)
                    {
                        expression = anyCall;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, anyCall);
                    }
                    
                }
                else if (expression == null)
                {
                    expression = GetExpression<T>(parameter, filter);
                }
                else
                {
                    expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, GetExpression<T>(parameter, filter) ?? Expression.Default(typeof(T)));
                }
            }
        }
        if (expression == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> newExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter);
        return newExp.Compile();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Translates user specified filters into expressions
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type the expression applies to</typeparam>
    /// <param name="parameter">The expression object</param>
    /// <param name="filter">The filter specified by the user</param>
    /// <returns>A expression that represents the filter</returns>
    private static Expression? GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression parameter, Filter filter)
    {
        MemberExpression member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, filter.Property ?? "");

        UnaryExpression constant = GetUnary(member, filter);

        // Get references for string methods
        MethodInfo? containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", [typeof(string)]);
        MethodInfo? toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
        MethodInfo? startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", [typeof(string)]);
        MethodInfo? endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", [typeof(string)]);

        // Error check
        if (containsMethod == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find string.Contains method", "Filter Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
        if (toLowerMethod == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find string.ToLower method", "Filter Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
        if (startsWithMethod == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find string.StartsWith method", "Filter Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
        if (endsWithMethod == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find string.EndsWith method", "Filter Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            switch (filter.Operator)
            {
                case Operator.Equals:
                    if (member.Type == typeof(string))
                        return Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(member, toLowerMethod), constant);
                    else
                        return Expression.Equal(member, constant);

                case Operator.NotEquals:
                    if (member.Type == typeof(string))
                        return Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Call(member, toLowerMethod), constant);
                    else
                        return Expression.NotEqual(member, constant);

                case Operator.GreaterThan:
                    return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);

                case Operator.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

                case Operator.LessThan:
                    return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);

                case Operator.LessThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

                case Operator.Contains:
                    if (member.Type == typeof(string))
                        return Expression.Call(Expression.Call(member, toLowerMethod), containsMethod, constant);
                    else
                        return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);
                
                case Operator.StartsWith:
                    if (member.Type == typeof(string))
                        return Expression.Call(Expression.Call(member, toLowerMethod), startsWithMethod, constant);
                    else
                        return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant);
                
                case Operator.EndsWith:
                    if (member.Type == typeof(string))
                        return Expression.Call(Expression.Call(member, toLowerMethod), endsWithMethod, constant);
                    else
                        return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Filter Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create constant for specified value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="member">Expression member</param>
    /// <param name="filter">User specified filter</param>
    /// <returns>A expression constant that represents the filter value</returns>
    private static UnaryExpression GetUnary(MemberExpression member, Filter filter)
    {
        if (filter.Value is string val)
        {
            return Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(val.ToLower().Trim()), member.Type);
        }

        return Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(filter.Value), member.Type);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Representation of a filter robject
/// </summary>
public class Filter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The object property to filter on
    /// </summary>
    public string? Property { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// What operation to compare with
    /// </summary>
    public Operator Operator { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The value to use for the comparison
    /// </summary>
    public object Value { get; set; } = "";
}

/// <summary>
/// Standard operators
/// </summary>
public enum Operator
{
    Contains,
    Equals,
    GreaterThan,
    GreaterThanOrEqual,
    LessThan,
    LessThanOrEqual,
    NotEquals,
    StartsWith,
    EndsWith
}

And I use it like this
Func<Component, bool>? expression = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Component>(filters);
if (expression == null)
{
    goto Fault;
}
return context.Components.Where(expression).AsQueryable();

Everything works fine when I specify any property in the Component class but when I specify the SupplierRecord I do not get any results back at all and i don't really understand why.
As you can see when the SupplierRecord is specified it translates into a filter for the SupplierPartNumber field with the user specified value.
Expression ex1 = GetExpression<SupplierRecord>(suppParameter, newFilter);
Generates a expression for the property that reads {s.SupplierPartNumber.ToLower().Contains(Convert("5", String))}
Expression ex2 = Expression.Lambda(ex1, suppParameter); 
Turns it into a lambda expression fine as well. {s => s.SupplierPartNumber.ToLower().Contains(Convert("5", String))} 
MethodCallExpression anyCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", [typeof(SupplierRecord)], records, ex2);
Getting the Any method to use on the list seems to work fine as well.
{t.SupplierRecords.Any(s => s.SupplierPartNumber.ToLower().Contains(Convert("5", String)))}
And finally creating a lambda expression for the component
Expression<Func<T, bool>> newExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter);
Seems to return the correct result
{t => t.SupplierRecords.Any(s => s.SupplierPartNumber.ToLower().Contains(Convert("5", String)))}
But when I run the query I don't get any results even though there should be one match.
If anyone has any idea what i might be missing that would be very helpful.
The reason this property is hardcoded at the moment is because I haven't decided on how to make the UI for the user to select subproperties.

DO NOT Compile Expression with EF Core. You should use proper extension method Queryable.Where with accepts Expression<Func<T, bool>>. Otherwise whole table will be populated into the memory.

I think I fixed it. I changed the expressionbuilder to return a Expression<Func<T, bool>> instead and passed that into a queryable like this
return context.Components.AsQueryable().Include(x => x.SupplierRecords).Where(expression)

Just as I was about to post this the answer hit me, but I thought I'd post it anyway if anyone else is having trouble with this in the future.
The problem was that the SupplierRecords aren't loaded in the context. Running an include on the supplier records before applying the expression solved the problem.
context.Components.Include(x => x.SupplierRecords).Load();
Func<Component, bool>? expression = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Component>(filters);
if (expression == null)
{
    goto Fault;
}
return context.Components.Where(expression).AsQueryable();


Are you sure this query isn't now running in memory instead of the database? Check the actual SQL being executed here, this could be extremely bad for performance.

I don't think so, because the return is an IQueryable. Not quite sure how to view the generated SQL.

Just because you have an IQueryable doesn't mean it hasn't already hit the database, I would expect the .Load to do that. EF Core, by default, outputs all the SQL it runs to the logs

I'll have to look more into this then. I'm not getting any output in the console at least. And telling the optionsbuilder to log to console doesn't do anything either.

Telling it to use Debug.Writeline worked better.
`dbug: 2024-04-02 13:39:11.272 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100]
(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
info: 2024-04-02 13:39:11.280 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101]
(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']`
Can't really attach everything in the comments though
